# MVC3 Razor and Modal popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i need to get a Modal popup that displays a form which will save data back to the db.
is there is good example of doing it? is Ajax more flexible or using jquery dialog?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've used the [JQuery UI Dialog plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) and use JQuery to load the modal dialog via ajax, and am quite happy with it.

I've had to hack up my code to give you something useful, so apologies for any syntax errors, but I use this jquery,

```
$('#MyAtag').click(function () {
    // Add a container for the modal dialog, or get the existing one
    var dialog = ($('#ModalDialog').length > 0) ? $('#ModalDialog') : $('<div id="ModalDialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
    // load the data via ajax
    $.get( 'mycontroller/myaction', {},
        function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            dialog.html(responseText);
            dialog.dialog({
                bgiframe: true,
                modal: true,
                width: 940,
                title: 'My Title'
            }); 
        }
    );
});
```

which binds a call to an ajax 'get' to the 'click' event of a link.  The ajax get request returns a partial view from the corresponding action in my MVC projec, which then shows up in the modal dialog.

Here is a rough example of what the controller could look like

```
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        // Do Some stuff
        //...

        // If the request is an ajax one, return the partial view
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("PartialViewName");

        // Else return the normal view
        return View();
    }
```

The view for the dialog would just be a normal partial view.

I use the following .css, which 'greys out' the page behind the modal dialog

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #AAA url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    opacity: .8;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=30);
}
```

You might need to muck around with the css for #ModalDialog to get it looking right,

Comment: You don't need to do anything different in your view/controller than you normally would - you just need to return a partial view if you don't want your _layout.cshtml included

Answer (score 1):

This is simple one but this is not a plugin:
http://deseloper.org/read/2009/10/jquery-simple-modal-window/

Jquery plugin based modal:
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using the first one in my MVC 3 app. Not the best, but works.

Comment: Couold you explain what you mean by not the best? What is it that you don't like? I haven't used either and I'm interested. Thanks.

Comment: Not the best: I mean if you follow #1, you will know the code but it lacks apply multiple themes, special effects if any. But you can add as you need. I like it as I don't need that much themeing and I want smaller script sizes. Hopefully you will find it easy too. If you have questions, please let me know.

Comment: you should put the css in your css file and js code in your js file for better reuse if you follow the first one.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery dialog.
there is also Jquery tools which you can use.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html

It has a very small footprint as well.

Comment: do we have examples with mvc 3 asp