# Ready ViewBag values from controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

In my controller I have the following ViewBag which has hard coded values for a drop down list

```
public ActionResult Order(string id, string printRequest)
{                            
this.ViewBag.PartialReasons = new List<string>() {" ", "Insufficient stock", "Suspended", "Retired", "Ordered Incorrectly", "Unable to deliver" };
}
```

I want to do is that once from a drop down the value "Unable to deliver" is selected, then have a alert POP up with "HELLO EVERYONE" appear, then user should be able to click on and save, my existing save function onclick is below,

in a nutshell just want to read a value from a controller viewbag.

```
    $('.pcss-save').click(function() {
        if (CheckSerialNumbersForQuantity()) {
            if (CheckReasons()) { //If Ordered incrrectly
                $('#genericmodal').find(".pcss-submit-genericmodal").unbind("click");
                $('#genericmodal').find(".modal-title").html("Confirmation");
                $('#genericmodal').find(".modal-body").html("This order will be Cancelled");
                $('#genericmodal').modal('show');
                $('#genericmodal').find(".pcss-submit-genericmodal").click(function() {
                    $("#orderform").submit();
                });
            } else {
                $("#orderform").submit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you should be able to call your ViewBag directly by using `@ViewBag.PartialReasons` and when the Razor engine renders the script, it will use those values in `@ViewBag.PartialReasons`.

You might want to do something like this.

```
    $('#yourDropDownID').on('change', function(){
        if(CheckReasons()){

          var genericModal = $('#genericmodal'); //Avoids rescanning the dom.
            genericModal.find(".pcss-submit-genericmodal").unbind("click");
            genericModal.find(".modal-title").html("Confirmation");
            genericModal.find(".modal-body").html("This order will be Cancelled");
            genericModal.modal('show');
            genericModal.find(".pcss-submit-genericmodal").click(function() {
                $("#orderform").submit();
        }
    });
```

And your check reasons might be something like this. This is kind of open to interpretation.

```
function CheckReasons(){
    var myReason = @String.Join(ViewBag.PartialReasons.ToArray());

    //loop and figure it out if your reason is selected and return true or false
}
```

This was all written off the top of my head, so it may need a little tweaking, but this should get you started with what you're looking to do.

UPDATE
You cannot access the ViewBag within your browser as it only exists server side. You need to render out a script that accomplishes what you desire on the server using ViewBag. The Razor engine will fill in the output from the C# code.

Comment: You can't access it through the client side, you can render out values however through the razor engine. `function CheckReasons(){
    var myReason = @String.Join(ViewBag.PartialReasons.ToArray());

    //loop and figure it out if your reason is selected and return true or false
}`

Comment: How do I do this @destructi6n

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955823/how-to-display-value-of-a-viewbag-in-my-view-with-a-js-function). This might get you on the right path to understanding

Answer (score 0):

First some questions:

- How are you loading the Viewbag values into the drop-down?
- Are you using Razor views?
- it seems you are asking multiple questions, so I'm going to try and hit each.

Typically drop downs are key-value pairs. With Razor views you can use:

```
@Html.DropDownList("reasonListID", new SelectList(ViewBag.PartialReasons, "reasonCode", "reasonName"))
```

This assumes that the viewbag object is a list of object with two properties `reasonCode` and `reasonName`.

Pure lists of strings are not really used to drive logic, you want to codify your potential values to give yourself clear and easy comparisons. In this way, you can simply look at `reasonCode` and not have to code for comparing your select value to "Some long string that may not have a lot of meaning in code" e.g. this would probably be in your `CheckReasons()` function.

```
if CheckReasons() == "UD") {
   showModal( "HELLO EVERYONE");
}
```

is easier than

```
if CheckReasons() == "Unable to deliver") {
   showModal("HELLO EVERYONE");
}
```

As far as popping the modal, it looks like you are using jquery, so take a look that this answered question: [MVC3 Razor and Modal popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566298/mvc3-razor-and-modal-popup)

Comment: in the controller I have a viewbag with hard coded values and I want to pass that viewbag values in a alert i.e. assign viewbag values in javascript then say if it equals something then alert